# regex for custom phone number?

Tags: java, regex, validation, number-formatting

Can Anyone give me regex for validate number which is

1. min 6 or max 15 digits number
2. it may be contain `(),-,#(` if there then only at first place followed by number),/,+

eg.

```
(079) 22861851
(079)22861851
079 22861851
22861851
079-26408300 / 8200
079 264 083 00 
9429527462
+919427957462
 #9427957462
```

i want it all above number to validate true withing one regex formula..can anyone help me.?

i have tried this

```
var phone_patternIndia = /^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}\d{2}(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$/;


var phone_patternUsa=/^([0-9]( |-)?)?(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?|[0-9]{3})( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})$/;

var phone_patternUsa1=/^[\\(]{0,1}([0-9]){3}[\\)]{0,1}[ ]?([^0-1]){1}([0-9]){2}[ ]?[-]?[ ]?([0-9]){4}[ ]*((x){0,1}([0-9]){1,5}){0,1}$/;
```

but its not working all time ..so decide to go with other pattern..

var phone_pattern=/^((\d{3}-?|(\d{3}))\s*\d{7}($|\s*/\s*\d{4}$)|\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{2}|+\d{12}|#\d{10})$/;

```
if (phone_pattern.test(personal_phone))
        {

            $("#restErrorpersonalphone").html('');
            $("#personal_phone").removeClass('borderColor');

        } else {
            $("#restErrorpersonalphone").html('Please enter valid phone number');
            $("#personal_phone").addClass('borderColor');
            flag = false;
        }
```

its always going in else condition

Comment: You don't mention `+` or `/` in any of your rules but they appear to be there

Comment: have edited my question...please see ..

Comment: if u dont want to help me then please dont atleast give down vote.i have tried the things..how u can just directly give me down vote??i know u people are expert..i have new in this regex thats y asked..if i know all then i dont need to post question here

Comment: `var`? has nothing to do with Java. Are you using Pascal?

Comment: am using in javascript within my java code

Comment: There are gazillion of these phone number question on SO. Have you taken a look at them and **adapt** - not just copy and paste?

Comment: yes...i have look there and even the code i have written is somewhat i done after googling and searching..but its too many pattern i had using with usapattern india pattern and etc.but i want one regex

Comment: its ok..leave it...dont answer the question.everyone just keep on down me.instead of helping me out..thanx..please dont help me..thanx..i am new bee in this..i dnt knw much..just a two week been to this..thats y asked..anyways...dont need ur help..thanx

Comment: What's up with all the initial down votes?  I can't stand that.  If you are going to down vote, please man-up and leave some constructive criticism.  Or that's my take on it at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your easiest approach to the problem would be to eliminate all non-digits and validate using the length of only the digits.

```
var digits=personal_phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
var isValid=false;
if (digits && digits.length>=10) {
    // You can fine-tune whether it starts with 1, matches an area code, etc here
    isValid=true;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, it's helpful to think of formatting as a function of presentation.  Validate only the value, not the format, and normalize the value to apply a consistent format during presentation (think of a list of numbers with same or different formats).  Consider that your users might cut and paste (916)555-4321 or 916.555.4321 into your app.  Both are valid, but if you're restrictive about formats, one user will not have as smooth an experience.

Comment: thanx///i should go with yr solution

Answer (score 2):

I strongly encourage breaking this into smaller regex and testing each individually, or else stripping out chars, then testing, but just a rough sample off top of my head that should help with your question ( not tested and only covers the examples you listed )...

```
(079) 22861851 => /^(\d{3}-?|\(\d{3}\))?\s*\d{7}(\s*\/\s*\d{4})?$/
(079)22861851  => same...
079 22861851   => same...
22861851       => same...
079-26408300 / 8200 => same...
079 264 083 00 => /^\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{2}$/
9429527462     => same as first regex
+919427957462  => \^\+\d{12}$/
 #9427957462   => /^#\d{10}$/
```

So, just combine them...

```
/^(\d{3}-?|\(\d{3}\))?\s*\d{7}($|\s*\/\s*\d{4}$)|\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{2}|\+\d{12}|#\d{10})$/
```

Comment: thanx for yr answer..its not working please see my updated question have posted what i have put in my code as u said.

Comment: np.  sorry man.  I'd test it but I gotta work.  let's look at the one's that fail, and narrow it down from there.  Which strings fail your regex checks?  And which regex do you expect to, but does not capture the pattern?